# Teams markdown "selectively" working on macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams, markdown

[Markdown on teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/use-markdown-formatting-in-microsoft-teams-4d10bd65-55e2-4b2d-a1f3-2bebdcd2c772) for macOS (not iOS) is working selectively... bold, italic, strikethrough, blockquote all work.

But the critical ones (in my pov) doesn't: inline quote using the backtick ` (like this: `test`) and the multiline code blocks, aka triple backtick

can anyone help?

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/9126, which version are you using? Maybe adding a comment there or creating a new ticket will provide more direct help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "New" Teams actually fixed this